# Branching model for flexible feature delivering (git)

Tags: git, continuous-integration, continuous-delivery, product-features

Suppose I have 2 features to be delivered (`A` and `B`). I have two primary branches (`develop` & `master`) for `staging` and `production` servers and 2 feature branches (`features/a` and `features/b`). When a feature is ready, I merge it to `develop` branch for testing. Let's assume that there wasn't found any bugs in feature `A` but there are some bugs in feature `B`, so I can't merge `develop` to `master` since feature `B` requires some fixes. But I need to deliver features that are ready (`A` in this case), so this approach doesn't work here. What other approaches can I try? I cannot switch branches for testing server because each feature may change the database schema, and I cannot always revert schema changes. I also cannot recreate database every time because I lose all the test data added manually by testers.

Comment: To clarify, you merge `features/a` or `features/b` into `develop` before the feature has been tested?

Comment: It has been tested locally by developers and unit-tests and was merged to deliver it to the staging server for testers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case there are no dependencies between the developed features you can use [git cherry-pick](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) to merge the commit(s) of one feature branch to the final master branch.

However, you should consider to introduce release branches to decouple the development branch from the master branch to avoid any misplaced/unpleasant commits in the final master branch.

Hence the workflow would be, developing in feature branch, merge to development branch, verifying, if okay, merge to release branch, if not okay, fix on feature branch. Finally, merge from release branch to master branch.

A release branch is also useful when some new features are ready which are not part of the current release but part of the next release. Then you have a release branch for the current release and one for the next release.

Comment: Thank you. But what should be the parent of `release` branch? And how would it solve the problem of separate delivering features `A` and `B`?

Comment: The parent of the release branch is the master. You are just merging working features, which were validated on the development branch, to the release branch. For example you validates Feature A works but Feature B not on the development branch, then you merge Feature A to the release branch and not Feature B.